# How to convert Eastern Time Zone to CENTRAL TIME ZONE

Tags: php, timezone, timestamp

I have a time that is being in Eastern Time Zone, but I want to adjust it to CENTRAL TIME ZONE. Both time zones are in USA. I never do it before? I don't know how to convert it. Please help me?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is one possible method:

```
$dt = new DateTime('2011-02-22 16:15:20', new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));
echo $dt->format('r') . PHP_EOL;

$dt->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('America/Chicago'));
echo $dt->format('r') . PHP_EOL;
```

You can get a list of available time zones with:

```
print_r(DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers());
```

Answer (score 2):

http://www.builderau.com.au/program/php/soa/Get-the-correct-time-by-converting-between-time-zones-with-PHP-and-PEAR/0,339028448,339273806,00.htm

Or use Zend_Date.

Answer (score 1):

Central Time is always 1 hour earlier than Eastern Time. To convert Eastern Time to Central Time, subtract one from the value of Eastern Time.

Comment: One should take caution, though, that this works for all but two hours out of the year... Since Daylight Saving Time changes in the US occur at 02:00 local time in each zone, this method won't work near those boundaries.